# How to not lose my information in props when i reaload my pages?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I'm new in react and i'm studing a method to make connections with Firebase to my Project.

With props I can pass an ID and search it in firebase, but when i reload my page, all the props are lost and i have this message in the image:
[The value is Undefined because the props are losing their values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or6aT.png)

Is there any other way for this information don't lost?

I dont try anything because idk what to do.
The ID in the props will be used in useEffect() on my page.

Edit:

There is the Cards Image:
[Cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCGlD.jpg)

And here it's when i click on the card "Pinscher":
[The page when i click on Pinscher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiPc1.png)

But when i Reload the page "Pinscher", i lost the Id passed with props.

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve this. The one that works best for you depends on what you are actually doing. Please show some example code to illustrate.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice my code are so big, but i can explain simply, i have dogs cards in my page, and when i click on it, it redirects to another page with some information about the dog i clicked. The information are in firebase and the specific id are passed in props. I will Edit my question and put some images with the cards and the page when i click on it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Check out [mcve] for some tips on creating an example that doesn't include all of your code.

Comment: With your description, one possible solution is to use react-router so that you can specify the id in the URL. Then when that URL is refreshed, you will still go the the correct view in your app.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way I know to persist data over a reload is to save it to localstorage or sessionstorage. Which one to use--and whether it's appropriate--depend on your actual use case, which we can't comment on without more knowledge of your project.

Assuming you did want to use that, a basic implementation would be to write helper functions when you set state to also save the data to storage. Your initial state load would then look for storage information as its default and then fallback to null if it can't find anything in storage.

```
  const [arbData, setArbData] = useState(window.localStorage.getItem('arbData'));

  const setArbDataWrapper = (data) => {
    setArbData(data);
    window.localStorage.set('arbData', data);
  }
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the help, i edit my question and i put some images about my project and what's happening. The images could help to recognize the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, images of your page aren't really helpful for this kind of thing. But the code I wrote above will help you. If you don't understand it, I think it means that you've accidentally skipped a step in learning and are out of your depth--which isn't a failure on your part, just means you need to step back a little bit and work on some more fundamentals before going farther. I have to do it all the time. Otherwise you end up missing some key things and it makes everything harder.

Comment: Thanks again and i will use your code to help me